# access the DOM, html table <th> and save table headings into variables.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to make changes to the DOM. I need to present the table content using paragaraphs.
For that I need to get the data per each row of table. How can I do this?

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output should be something like this - Name-Jill, Surname-Smith, Age-50 and Name-Eve Surname-Jackson Age-94

I have written something like this,

```
  $("table tr").each(function () {
        text = "";
  $(this).find('th').each(function () {
            //save the column headings to variables
        });

        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            text += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        alert(text);
    });
```

It will print row by row. But needs to add the  hedings infront of each. I think I have to use arrays or something like that to store the table headings and use it in each .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just store a reference to the `th` elements in a variable and then iterate over the other cells by row. You can also just store the text of the headings in an array:

```
var headings = $('th').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();

$("table tr:has(td)").each(function () {
    var text = "";
    $(this).children('td').each(function (index) {
        text += headings[index] + ":" + $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Just wondering: in order to access the array object in `headings`, don't you need to chain `.get()`?